# state' is not defined no-undef in App.js file

Tags: reactjs

whenever i declare state in App.js file in my react.js project i get error state' is not defined no-undef and also getting this error while declaring functions.

i have looked for various place for solution but don't get the solution.

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import Counters from "./components/counters";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";
import "./App.css";
function App() {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };
  handleDelete = counterId => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
  handleReset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState(counters);
  };

  incrementHandle = counter => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counter[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <main className="container">
        <Counters
          counters={this.state.counters}
          onIncrement={this.incrementHandle}
          onDelete={this.handleDelete}
          onReset={this.handleReset}
        />
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

./src/App.js
  Line 7:   'state' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 15:  'handleDelete' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 19:  'handleReset' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 27:  'incrementHandle' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use state in React Function Component you need [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Your component will look something like this when using hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";  // import useState too
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import Counters from "./components/counters";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  // useState function returns an array with two items. First is your state object (similar to `this.state`)
  // and second is a function to update the state object, ie. the first item of array (similar to `this.setState`, but with minor changes, see react docs for more info, linked above)
  const [counters, setCounters] = useState([  // useState to set initial counter value
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]);

  // use setCounters method to update the counters state 
  const handleDelete = counterId => setCounters(counters => counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId));

  const handleReset = () => setCounters(counters => counters.map(c => {
    c.value=0;
    return c;
  }));

  const incrementHandle = counter => {
    const counters_copy = [...counters];  // rename to counters_copy to avoid having global and local counters variable name conflict
    const index = counters_copy.indexOf(counter);
    counters_copy[index] = { ...counter };
    counter_copy[index].value++;
    setCounters({ counters_copy });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <main className="container">
        <Counters
          counters={counters} // no need of this.state
          onIncrement={incrementHandle}  // no need to this
          onDelete={handleDelete}  // no need to this
          onReset={handleReset}  // no need to this
        />
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Or use can use a class component instead of function and use state old way(without hooks).

```
// imports stays the same
...

class App extends React.Component {  // convert to class
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {  // initial state in constructor
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };

  ...
  // handler functions stays the same

  render(){  // return goes inside render function
    return (...);  // contents of return stays the same
  }
}

export default App;
// don't actually write ... , it just means what you had in your question the code stays same
```

Hooks can't be used in class components and `this.state` can't be used in function component.
So if your component is:
`function` -> use hooks, i.e. `useState`, `useRef` etc.
`class` -> use `this.state` and `this.setState`

Also function components has better performance and code minification, so I recommend using that. Your app will perform better and will have smaller bundle size.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine to work by changing it to a class extends component. you have to 'imrc' and I commented out the 'imr'. Mosh's workspace is already setup like this when he clicks on App.JS so I wonder if that's what the old App.JS used to look like by default?

Replace - `function App() {`
with - `class App extends Component {`

also, add render {} for the class

along with above changed also replace - `import React from "react";`

with - `import React, { Component } from "react";`

at the top of the imports.

Hope it will fix your error, since its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are U using React Hooks, because functions by default are dumb/stateless components and therefore do not have any state by default. I have never used hooks before but I can definitely checkout the the documentation to help you out. However you can convert the functional component into a class based component to make your life a lot easier rather than using hooks.

Answer (score 0):

We both watched the YouTube React tutorial and followed up on the syntax. The producer makes this React using an old version, and you may use a brand-new one.

New React default app.js inside recommend "function App() {..."

My solution is to replace it with "Class App extends Component{" on your above line 7.

it will be working.